# Remote ssh through multiple machines

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to ssh from machine A to machine B and execute ssh command from machine B onto machine C to execute a command  on machine C, all in one step from machine A. But it is not working after I get into machine B. It is getting stuck there. The output is shown below:

---

```
[root@A ~]# ssh  -t -t  root@192.168.40.152 << EOF
ssh -t  -t  root@192.168.40.153 << HK
hostname
HK
EOF

root@192.168.40.152's password:
ssh -t  -t  root@192.168.40.153 << HK
hostname
HK
Last login: Fri Apr 14 08:53:33 2017 from 192.168.40.151
[root@B ~]# ssh -t  -t  root@192.168.40.153 << HK
> hostname
> HK
root@192.168.40.153's password: redhat
```

---

It is stopping at the above point and not executing the command 'hostname' on machine C.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
ssh -J root@192.168.40.152 root@192.168.40.153 "hostname"
```

This will do the ProxyJump through 192.168.40.152 and execute hostname command on 192.168.40.153.

Please note that you need to have at least OpenSSH version 7.3 in order to have -J option.